# In what order does setValue:forKey: search for the KVC-compliant method or ivar?

Tags: objective-c, ios, key-value-coding

Some background:

I wrote a UIScrollView derived class with an outlet named contentView, similar to the following:

```
@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView {
    IBOutlet UIView * contentView;
}

...

@end
```

My outlet, in this case is an iVar, not a property. I made use of my class in Interface builder and connected a view to the `contentView` outlet. At runtime, however, I discovered that my iVar was still nil and was not set to the desired view object.

Some experimentation revealed that if I renamed the outlet or made my outlet a property instead of an iVar, all would work fine. Further research showed that with my outlet as an iVar named `contentView`, loading the nib would actually connect my desired view object to a private iVar in UIScrollView named `_contentView`.

I know that nib loading uses KVC to set values and that the KVC `setValue:forKey:` method will set a value using any of the following:

- `set{Key}:` method
- `{key}` iVar
- `_{key}` iVar

I suspect, but cannot prove, that an attempt to find the `set{Key}:` method occurs first, and if that fails, an enumeration of iVars is undertaken to find the `{key}` or `_{key}` iVar next. This enumeration probably occurs in an order that processes iVars from superclasses before subclasses.

Is there a documented order in which the above candidates are attempted? In what order are members of superclasses attempted in relation to subclasses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific search algorithm is documented in the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for finding the reference.